# Which HTTP status to return if a downstream service I depend on returned 500 error

Tags: microservices, http-response

My service `B` is part of a chain of services and calls a downstream service `C`.

`A --> B --> C`

Service `C` is returning HTTP 500 errors for *any* error it faced, including bad requests or input validation errors that normally should be 4** errors.

There is no option to change / update service C.

Since service B is stuck between the calling application A and service C, there are many occasions that service C will return HTTP 500 only because the input params sent by A are wrong.

As the writer of service B, I'm not aware of the different validation service C will do on the input and I definitely don't want to duplicate them in B.

I wonder what should be the best HTTP error code to return when C returns 500? At the moment I can't differentiate between real server error or bad input.

The problem with `return whatever C returns to you` is that whenever my service returns 500 error, we will need to start debugging and understanding if the cause of the error is from B or it is just a propagation of the error from service C.

Comment: Is the `A` a client, `B` your service, and `C` a third-party application?

Comment: Does C only return an error code or is there a payload with an error message ?
It is quite dirty but you could try to parse the most common error messages to return appropriate error codes for them and default to 500 for the others.

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan yes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the status 500, but the fact that you receive an *inappropriate* status 500.

Assuming that the client is aware of the situation, you could return status 500 plus a message that this is caused by service C. But if you *can* figure out what the correct status would have been, return that.

So your client will receive: Correct status codes from your server, including sometimes an appropriate status 500. Or a status 500 marked as “caused by C”. Or some other status, created by you to replace a status 500 from C.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of `C` you should send valid data to get a successful response. If it answers back with 500 it is an issue for `C`.
If you know what the valid request looks like then you can validate the data in `B` sent by `A` and inform the client about the validation error. In case when the client data is valid, send it to `C` and get the expected result.